# How to merge previous changes to the head after roll back?

Tags: svn, merge

Assume we are in revision 10, make some changes, obtaining function A, commit, now in revision 11.
But the changes are difficult to test. So, the maintainer rollback to revision 10, and commit, now in revision 12.

After some other commit, we are in revision 20. And I decide to test the function A, so I update my project to the head, revision 20.

**The question** is how to merge the changes in revision 11 to the head while keeping changes after  revision 12.

I have tried

```
svn merge -c 11 svn://path/to/project/trunk .
```

I am in the local trunk dir. But it don't work since there is nothing in the stdout and my project remains the same.

I have tested

```
svn diff -r 11:20 svn://path/to/project/trunk/fileA ./fileA
```

It did give the diff between two revisions.

Comment: Show result of merge (the *same merge*) with `--dry-run` option

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. The following should work:

```
svn merge -c 11 svn://path/to/project/trunk .
```

You need to merge changeset 11 if you want to replicate the changes made in revision 11.

Comment: Sorry, it meant to be 11, but I make a mistake here.  What I tried is 'svn merge -c 11 svn://path/to/project/trunk .' , but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your merge command is formally correct
2. Clean applying of old changeset to new (modified) code is *not guaranteed* - unified diff have to be applied in context, which can be changed after r11 and you'll get rejected hunks and merge-conflict as result: check for new unversioned files in your WC
3. You diff is bad and useless for your case: if, instead of merge, you want to get diff for changes in r11 and apply it by hand with `svn patch`, you have to `svn diff -c 11 > r11.patch`

Comment: I have serval changelist but the avtive cl is clean. Finally, I diff two versions manually since the amount of changed files is not large.